# How to determine the relationship between faces, bend angles, etc from a iges CAD model

Tags: algorithm, vector, geometry, cad, step

Hie guys I'm working on an web app for feature extraction from an IGES(file format) CAD model. I have extracted and stored all the entities from the iges file e.g shell entity, face entity, loop, edges, and vertex entity. Also I managed to draw the model using three.js. 
I followed the the algorithms in the document [here](https://www.google.co.zw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0_6-dv9TMAhUpKsAKHc7uCOMQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780387232904-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-315596-p52495652&usg=AFQjCNHdsr1_5B1eti5wSZI7xGOvm9OT2g&bvm=bv.121658157,d.ZGg) until the point where we extract feature from the model itself. The document assumes that the edge between two faces is a line and so calculating the angles and edge concavity becomes easy:
[image]
The algorithm used is as follows:
[image]

In my case, however, the edge between the faces is a semi cylindrical in shape and this edge is detected by the app(I guess because of the entities in the iges file) as having 4 faces( the outer & inner faces and the faces on the sides). When I draw the wireframe model this is what is displayed:
[image]

1. I would like your help in finding the best algorithm to find the angles between two faces without using the edge face in the process just like in the first image( i.e as if the edge is just a line).
2. How do you calculate the edge direction( as stated in the above document)

THANK YOU.

Comment: I would ignore the edge shape (if not line then it is not planar face and bend angle does not have a meaning on the edge) Instead I would use just the face normals `n1,n2` for example: `angle = acos(dot(n1,n2)/(|n1|.|n2|))`